# Select string before character

Tags: sql-server

I have a field that may or may not be suffixed with an underscore and a number. I would like to select the part of the string before the _, but the _ is not always present

In another question I found this:

```
SUBSTRING([LineNumber], 0, CHARINDEX('_', [LineNumber]))
```

It works nice for MH31014329_1, which it then turns into MH31014329, but where there is no _1 it produces a blank

A case statement to test for ='' works but this record set is >100k lines, and I don't think it is efficient.

How can I do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a "FAIL-SAFE" to the `charindex()`  It will do no harm if one already exists.

```
SUBSTRING([LineNumber], 0, CHARINDEX('_', [LineNumber]+'_'))
```